# Would Apple allow the use iAP in this way?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I have an app that I do not plan to ever allow the user to pay to remove ads.

However, I want my beta testers to be able to do this in the final project. Would creating an iAP (that you can't actually access from within the app because I don't want people to buy it) that removes ads work? I would just give my testers a promo code from iTunes Connect, that they could redeem (or I found this cool app called *Tokens for Mac* that allows you to create links) which would remove the ads.

I don't want to deal with coding some sort of login solution, or have static redeem codes in the app that just anyone could use (that way if a user gives out their code anyone could technically use it), I figure using Apple IAP would only allow it to be redeemed once, therefore securing it.

Is this an okay way of doing it, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### I wouldn't risk it...

You might be able to squeak by, but I wouldn't risk it.  Even if you do get your app approved once, your first update might get rejected for the same reason, or your second, etc.  They'll definitely know your app has in-app purchase capability, and it might pop red flags because you don't have a Restore button, etc.

There's a very, *very* fine line with Apple between "discouraged" and "disallowed," and it's always better (and less of a headache for you) to avoid skirting rules wherever possible, even if you're technically not breaking any.

### ...but there are plenty of better, and easier, ways.

That being said, I would look into using a DEBUG macro, or something similar.  You can isolate parts of your code that only work when you're working on a DEBUG version of your app, rather than a RELEASE version, or vice versa.

Doing that, you could do something as simple as this:

```
code code code...

#ifdef RELEASE
    ad code here...
#endif

code code code...
```

This way, your ad will only appear if the user is running a Release version of the app.  Your testers won't see ads, your actual users will, and you won't need to do anything else about it.

Comment: The testers would be using the release version, however (this is after testing is complete, I just want the original testers to have special privileges on the Release build for helping me). I don't want to force anyone to use TestFlight just so they can see the app without ads, especially since anything I may release to testflight may not be as stable or finished as release.

Comment: @R3TRI8UTI0N  Ah, so you're talking about the actual, post-release version available on the App Store?  Then no, you'd need some kind of login system, I think, or some way to differentiate between *these* people and the rest of your users.

Comment: It would be distributed via TestFlight. However, once the app is released to the app store, I want the testers to be able to have no ads since they helped me. Basically that's their payment. Does that make more sense?

Comment: @R3TRI8UTI0N  Ah, I see now.  Out of curiosity, why not just do the actual in-app purchase route?  Plenty of apps make good money by letting people pay to not see ads.  Any reason you aren't making the in-app purchase available to everyone, and then giving your testers promo codes?

Comment: I've seen a few studies where allowing the removal of ads really doesn't help at all financially, specifically at the $.99 tier. You're better off keeping the users that use your app enough to be annoyed with the ads to continue being shown ads, than lose ad revenue because you gave them a $.99 option months ago. Also, I don't want to nickle and dime people, yet I still feel testers should have some sort of benefit for helping. edit> I suppose i could still add the recover button, just not a buy button.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not Apple (and therefore, anything I predict they will or won't do could be wrong) but no, you won't be able to do this.

Why?

- In order to do what you suggest, you will need to have one or more *live* IAP SKUs attached to the app at submission time
- In order to have your app pass review, Apple will review the SKU(s) as well as the app
- In order to pass review, Apple *will* verify your IAP functionality (including restore purchases) and will reject your app if they cannot identify where these functions (purchase and restore) happen
- In order to do what you're suggesting (even allowing that you get beyond the hurdles listed), you would need an in-app purchase promo code (which does not yet seem to be commonly available), as opposed to the app-level promo codes that are usable in limited quantities by all developers.

  All in all and given the restrictions, this is not an appropriate tool on iOS to achieve goals you list.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that your beta testers are not testing the app that you put on the store. Any problems with ads won't be found. You really should only beta-test exactly what you intend to sell.

Comment: You don't understand my question. Please view the comment I made to @Nerrrolken post.

Comment: I do understand your question. You don't understand the meaning of testing. Testing something other than you are shipping is pointless.